# Is there a way to add 2 different types to a new List in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add 2 lists together but they are each of a different type, is there a way to do that?

My 2 lists

```
var customer = _context.GetInsuredData.FromSqlRaw("Execute dbo.GetDataID {0}", id).ToList();
var vehicle = _context.GetVehicleData.FromSqlRaw("Execute dbo.GetDataVehicle {0}", id).ToList();
```

My context:

```
 public virtual DbQuery<Insured> GetInsuredData { get; set; }
 public virtual DbQuery<Vehicle> GetVehicleData { get; set; }
```

Comment: The better question is why do you need `Insured` and `Vehicle` in one list?

Comment: you can use a dictionary if you want, but you can't merge both different types together

Comment: Ask yourself are 'Insured' and 'Vehicle' related in anyway? You can restructure these classes to work as one type, and then you are able to have a list of one type

Comment: Suppose if you used `object` as the type of the list, but I don't see how that would be useful. https://dotnetfiddle.net/srx9kM

Comment: @TiesonT. - I cringe every time someone suggests that. Hopefully OP doesn't just take that path and roll with it. I doubt they'd actually understand the implications here. Seems to be a fairly common beginner mistake with questions like these. I completely agree that that approach won't be useful.

Comment: No, you can't do that. A list is defined as a collection of a single type. If the two types have a common base or interface, you can define the list as a collection of *that* type and then add both of the derived types to it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to associate the values in each list together?  Like does each vehicle have a matching insured?

Comment: The short answer is: No, not *unless* the classes are related somehow (such as a common base class). If they are not, other approaches (such as using `object`) are probably just hacky workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

**Option 1** - Let the classes implement a common interface (or inherit a common base class):

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{ }

public class Insured : ICommonInterface
{ }

public class Vehicle : ICommonInterface
{ }
```

...then use a list with the generic type of the interface:

```
var list = new List<ICommonInterface>();
objectList.AddRange(insureds);
objectList.AddRange(vehicles);
```

**Option 2** - Declare a list with the generic type `object`:

```
var list = new List<object>();
list.AddRange(insureds);
list.AddRange(vehicles);
```

You may need to rethink why you want to do this. Do the classes have something in common? Then use the interface/base class option. If not, what is the reason of adding objects of the different types to the same list? The problem you actually are trying to solve probably lies out of context of this question.

Comment: To OP: PLEASE do not even consider option 2. You're asking for trouble with that approach. You might want to step back rethink the design of your code. Using the `object` type directly isn't actually what you want 99% of the time.